# MDriven Save OR Mappings to Database

Tags: mdriven

Is there a way to Save OR Mappings to Database programatically.
There is an option in the EcoPMP bottom button I want to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  one of the DBEvolutionForm.EvolveDB() functions.

i.e. 
    EvolveDB(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IPersistenceMapperDb persistenceMapper, 
      ITypeSystemService typeSystemService, bool silent);